# Gulp Sass - How to properly name the output css?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm reading a tutorial about sass [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-sass) then I tried some other approach and I cant get the answer in this tutorial. Theres the problem. I have this code in my gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('compileNavbar', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/css/sass/**/*.navbar.scss')
        .pipe(sass('navbar.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'));;
});
```

As of now, I only have assets/css/sass/guest.navbar.scss and this code locates the scss files correctly and puts the output css file in the correct directory **BUT** the css is named as **guest.navbar.css** which I didnt expect. I want it to be named as **navbar.css** but how to?

Comment: I have no experience with Gulp, but have you tried renaming the input file to `navbar.scss`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`gulp-sass` doesn't take any file name parameters. Use `gulp-rename` to rename your files. If you have more than one `.navbar.scss` files you want to concatenate into one `navbar.css` files, feel free to use `gulp-concat`. This one takes a file name parameter :-)

Install `gulp-rename` with `npm install gulp-rename --save-dev`

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

return gulp.src('assets/css/sass/**/*/*.navbar.scss')
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(rename('navbar.css'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css');
```

or

Install `gulp-concat` with `npm install gulp-concat --save-dev`

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

return gulp.src('assets/css/sass/**/*/*.navbar.scss')
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(concat('navbar.css'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css');
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark this answer as correct. Both methods worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Hi! I tried the first method and it creates an empty file with the name containing `.scss` instead of `.css`. Here is the function I am using: http://pastebin.com/GJLN5TQG

Comment: Neither worked for me, until of course I remembered to add gulp-rename pacakge to my dev dependencies ;)

Comment: rename doesn't seem to be stable.

Comment: `gulp-concat` worked a treat for me. I didn't realise you could effectively concat a single file to a new name.