# gulp-sass modifying generated filename (style.css)

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Using `gulp-sass` automatically calls the file that is compiled to css `style.css`. Does anyone know how this filename can be modified? i.e. so I can change it to `style2.css`

Please see `gulpfile.js` below.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('./dev/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./prod/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp Sass - How to properly name the output css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535178/gulp-sass-how-to-properly-name-the-output-css)

Comment: To be clear about what's happening: `gulp-sass` output isn't defaulting to the basename `style`, it's keeping your input file's basename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try gulp-rename - looks pretty easy.